# How to have the axis ticks in both top and bottom, left and right of a heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I am trying to draw a big heatmap with sns.heatmap function. However, since the map is too big, it's a little hard to find the xtick label or  ytick label with corresponding rows and columns. Can I add the xtick and xlabels also on the top and ytick and ylabels also on the right??

I have tried many different ways. But they all didn't work.

Answer (score 10):

The usual way would be via [`tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html), which has the `labelrotation` parameter, and accepts `rotation`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import seaborn as sns

uniform_data = np.random.rand(10, 12)
ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data)
ax.tick_params(right=True, top=True, labelright=True, labeltop=True, labelrotation=0)

plt.show()
```

[image]

- Without `labelrotation=0` or `rotation=0`

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes. Actually you totally understand my question. But the main point I was struggling before is that the x and y axis labels are all text labels in my figure. When I use the ax.tick_params,  the rotation for all labels will be messed up, which makes the labels could not be displayed clearly.

Comment: So I actually tried the ax.tick_params function in the very beggining for solving my problem, but the rotation could not be figured out. Then I wanna ask if there are any other ways for solving this problem. I will be very appreciate if you can further help be with this problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What about `rotation=0`  ?

Answer (score 4):

Axis ticks for all sides can be placed using `tick_params` from matplotlib

```
#Get sample correlation data to plot something. 'data' is a dataframe
corr=data.corr()

#Create Heatmap
axr = sns.heatmap(corr,cmap="coolwarm", annot=True, linewidths=.5,cbar=False)

#Set all sides
axr.tick_params(right=True, top=True, labelright=True, labeltop=True,rotation=0)

#Rotate X ticks
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
```

[image]